# QML/C++ Several tables on one screen with independent models

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a simple QML Table with the model defined in C++. I want to display several similar tables on one screen, but with different data. Each table must be able to be updated independently.
The most obvious idea is to declare several instances of TableModel and initialize them with actual data, but as far as I see, the table is bound to class itself and not to its instance. How can this be done with QML and C++?

**tablemodel.h**

```
#ifndef TABLEMODEL_H
#define TABLEMODEL_H

#include "qqmlintegration.h"
#include <QObject>
#include <QAbstractTableModel>

class TableModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QML_ELEMENT
    QML_ADDED_IN_MINOR_VERSION(1)
public:
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex & = QModelIndex()) const override;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex & = QModelIndex()) const override;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const override;
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const override;
};

#endif
```

**tablemodel.cpp**

```
#include "tablemodel.h"

int TableModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex &) const
{
    return 200;
}

int TableModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex &) const
{
    return 2;
}

QVariant TableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    switch (role) {
    case Qt::DisplayRole:
        return getParameterValue(index);//this function is different for every instance of the table
    default:
        break;
    }
    return QVariant();
}

QHash<int, QByteArray> TableModel::roleNames() const
{
    return { {Qt::DisplayRole, "display"} };
}
```

**Main.qml**

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Window
import QtQuick 2.12
import TableModel 0.1
Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Table view")

    TableView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        columnSpacing: 1
        rowSpacing: 1
        clip: true

        model: TableModel {}

        delegate: Rectangle {
            implicitWidth: 100
            implicitHeight: 50
            Text {
                text: display
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>
#include "tablemodel.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    qmlRegisterType<TableModel>("TableModel",0,1,"TableModel");
    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(u"qrc:/TableViewExample/Main.qml"_qs);
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreationFailed,
        &app, []() { QCoreApplication::exit(-1); },
        Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: "but as far as I see, the table is bound to class itself and not to its instance." What makes you say that?

Comment: @GrecKo because I don't instantiate explicitly any TableModel object.

Comment: I do not know what both sentences you are discussing in the above comments mean; can't you just write if you are talking about the table view or the model? BTW, have you even tried to instantiate more than 1 table view / table model pair in your QML? And have you tried to put a breakpoint on the model's constructor to see how many times it was being called? Sure does not look like you have...

Comment: You actually instantiated the model as `TableModel {}` in `main.qml`, and it would be bound to the class if you registered it as a singleton, which you didn't.